# phpmailler disable_functions

Tags: php, sendmail

all below functions are disabled and so phpmailler is not sending e-mail. please help me which one is effecting the phpmailler?

shell_exec,exec,system,glob,cat,dl,openbasedir,popen,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,escapeshellcmd,escapeshellarg,show_source,posix_mkfifo,mysql_list_dbs,get_current_user,getmyuid,pconnect,link,symlink,pcntl_exec,ini_alter,parse_ini_file,leak,apache_child_terminate,posix_kill,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,proc_terminate,syslog,fpassthru,allow_url_fopen,stream_select,socket_select,socket_create,socket_create_listen,socket_create_pair,socket_listen,socket_accept,socket_bind,socket_strerror,pcntl_fork,pcntl_signal,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_wtermsig,openlog,apache_get_modules,apache_get_version,apache_getenv,apache_note,apache_setenv,virtual,name

Comment: are you sure it is a diabled function that is causing it, is there a chance your code is the malfunctioning part? post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. Contact with administrator of machine or change webhosting.

Answer (score 0):

this  is send code

```
<?php 
$mail  = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport

 $body = '<div style="margin:auto; width:700px; height:auto; border:1px #A4A3A3 solid; border-radius:10px; font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

            <div style="margin:5px 5px 10px 5px;">

                <div style="background:#4C4C4C; height:26px; border-radius:5px; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; padding:10px 0 3px 10px; text-align:center">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:20px; ">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">SATILIK / KIRALIK :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left; ">'.$bulletin['Sales'].'</div>
                  </div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:20px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">ODA :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left; ">'.$roomary['R_Name'].'</div>
                </div>


                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">KISIM :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.$Regionary['K_Name'].'</div>
                </div>  

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">BLOK :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.$bulletin['Block'].'</div>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">KAT :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.$Floorary['F_Name'].'</div>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">CEPHE :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.$Facadeary['C_Name'].'</div>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;"> FIYAT :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.formatprice($bulletin['Price']).$curr.'</div>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">DURUM :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.$Statuseary['D_Name'].'</div>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">ANAHTAR :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.$bulletin['ana'].'</div>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">NOT :  </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left;">'.$bulletin['Note'].'</div>
                </div>  

                <div style="clear:both; margin-top:10px; height:50px; padding-top:15px">
                    <div style="width:245px; float:left; padding-left:10px; font-size:15px;">&nbsp; </div>
                    <div style="width:400px; float:left; font-size:23px; font-weight:bold;"> Tesekkur Ederiz</div>
                </div>  

            </div>
                    <div style="clear:both; height:10px; padding-top:15px"></div>

        </div>';


// fetch USER for SEND MAIL 

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bul_user WHERE B_id = ".$bul_id);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        $row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user where Id = '".$row['U_id']."' AND mail_option = '1'"); 
        $ary = mysql_fetch_array($row);

        $mail->AddAddress($ary['Em']);
    } 


// FETCH ATTACHMENT FOR SEND MAIL 

    $imgins = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bul_img` WHERE B_id ='".$bul_id."'");
    while($rowimg = mysql_fetch_array($imgins))
    {
        $mail->AddAttachment($rowimg['image_path']);      // attachment
    }

  $mail->SetFrom($_SESSION['Em']);

  $mail->Subject    = "Have a New Messaj ";
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else { 

  }

?>
```